# Belief updating on censored exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian, exponential-distribution

Consider an agent who knows that the quality requirement ($t$) of its principal for a product follows the density function $f(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda (t-x)}$ for all $t>x$ and is zero for $t\leq x$. This is basically an exponential distribution that starts at time $t$.
The agent now delivers a product of quality $y$ to the principal who declines the product (The principal has no reason to lie about its requirements). The agent can now use this information to update the pdf via the parameter $x$.

Am I correct that the agent's updated belief about the p.d.f. is $f(t|t>y)=\lambda e^{-\lambda (t-y)}$ for all $t>y$ and is $0$ for $t\leq y$? If not, what would it be?

Comment: How you revise your prior depends upon your method and assumptions.  The proper method (provably optimal, consistent, ...) is to use Bayesian inference.  If you *know* or *assume* that the only uncertainty is with the value of $\lambda$, then Bayesian inference will give a new posterior over $\lambda$.

Comment: I think it is not exactly Bayesian updating in this case. It is not that the agent makes an observation of the event and then updates its belief about this event. It is basically, that this event is once drawn from the pdf. which I described. This event is observed by a third party, which informs the agent not about the exact time, but only that the event will be later than $y$. Using that information, what is the new distribution the agent assumes?

Comment: You need to think about what led the agent to say that.  If the agent waited until time $t$ and then stopped watching because of another appointment, then what you say is reasonable.  If the agent watched until the event occurred and then rounded down a bit, then perhaps not. (For example if a brand advertisement  tells you it is in the top two most popular, you might reasonably think it is more likely to be the second most popular than the first, because otherwise it might have said something else)

Comment: I changed the context a bit and tried to be more clear.

Comment: need clarification on whether $y$ is a time or not. in your stated problem you call it a quality.  is $y$ a time? what are units of $y$?

Answer (score 1):

Assume the agent has an "improper" flat prior on $[0,\infty)$ over $x$. If $y$ is rejected the posterior over $x$ is a flat (improper uniform) distribution over $[y,\infty)$. If it is not rejected we write the likelihood function over $x$ as $L(x| y)=\lambda e^{-\lambda (y-x)}$ when $x \leq y$ and $L(x| y)=0$ otherwise. Because $\lambda e^{-\lambda (y-x)}$ is increasing in $x$, this is maximized when $x=y$ as you suggested.